# C# Linq Queries - Not In DataTable

Tags: c#, linq

I have got a couple of datatables, 1 for Products ordered by Rank and 1 for Customer Purchase History. What i'm trying to do is pull the top 250 products that a customer isn't already buying. I have got the below code as a test but I'm stuck at the last part.

```
class Program
{
    static DataTable Product = new DataTable("Product");
    static DataTable OrderHistory = new DataTable("OrderHeader");
    static DataTable OrderLines = new DataTable("OrderLines");
    static DataTable CustomerHistory = new DataTable("CustomerHistory");

   public static void LoadTables()
    {
        Product.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[]
        {
            new DataColumn("ProductID",typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("ProductCode",typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("Rank",typeof(int))
        });
        Product.Rows.Add(200001, 10001, 1);
        Product.Rows.Add(200002, 10002, 2);
        Product.Rows.Add(200003, 10003, 3);
        Product.Rows.Add(200004, 10004, 4);
        Product.Rows.Add(200005, 10005, 5);
        Product.Rows.Add(200006, 10006, 6);
        Product.Rows.Add(200007, 10007, 7);
        Product.Rows.Add(200008, 10008, 8);

        OrderHistory.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[]
        {
            new DataColumn("CustomerID", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("OrderID", typeof(int))
        });
        OrderHistory.Rows.Add("ABC001", 123);
        OrderHistory.Rows.Add("ABC002", 124);
        OrderHistory.Rows.Add("ABC003", 125);
        OrderHistory.Rows.Add("ABC004", 126);
        //OrderHistory.Rows.Add("BA009", 127);

        OrderLines.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[]
        {
            new DataColumn("OrderID",typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("ProductID", typeof(int))
        });
        OrderLines.Rows.Add(123, 200001);
        OrderLines.Rows.Add(123, 200002);
        OrderLines.Rows.Add(123, 200003);
        OrderLines.Rows.Add(123, 200004);
        OrderLines.Rows.Add(123, 200005);
        OrderLines.Rows.Add(124, 200006);
        OrderLines.Rows.Add(124, 200006);
        OrderLines.Rows.Add(124, 200007);
        OrderLines.Rows.Add(124, 200008);
        OrderLines.Rows.Add(124, 200009);
        OrderLines.Rows.Add(127, 200001);
        OrderLines.Rows.Add(127, 200002);
        OrderLines.Rows.Add(127, 200009);
        OrderLines.Rows.Add(127, 200008);
        OrderLines.Rows.Add(127, 200007);
        OrderLines.Rows.Add(126, 200006);
        OrderLines.Rows.Add(126, 200005);
        OrderLines.Rows.Add(126, 200008);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LoadTables();

        var rows = (from orderLines in OrderLines.AsEnumerable()
                    join orderHistory in OrderHistory.AsEnumerable()
                    on orderLines["OrderID"] equals orderHistory["OrderID"]
                    select new
                    {
                        CustomerID = orderHistory["CustomerID"],
                        ProductID = orderLines["ProductID"]
                    }).Distinct();

        CustomerHistory.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[]
        {
            new DataColumn("CustomerID"),
            new DataColumn("ProductID")
        });

        foreach (var row in rows)
        {
            CustomerHistory.Rows.Add(row.CustomerID, row.ProductID);
        }

        //foreach (DataRow row in CustomerHistory.Rows)
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine(row[0].ToString() + "\t" + row[1].ToString());
        //}

        var topSellers = "Select Top250 CustomerHistory.CustomerID, Product.ProductCode";

    }
}
```

I don't have to use datatables if that makes it easier to use Linq? I just can't think of a better way to store the results of the database queries. The information is coming from a ctreeSQL database through ODBC if that information is helpful?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want the top 250 products no customer has purchased, and not the top 250 per customer.

Create a `HashSet` to hold the purchased product IDs:

```
var productsPurchased = new HashSet<int>(CustomerHistory.AsEnumerable().Select(ch => ch.Field<int>("ProductID")).Distinct());
```

Find all the products never purchased and sort by rank, then take the top 250:

```
var topSellers = (from p in Product.AsEnumerable()
                  where !productsPurchased.Contains(p.Field<int>("ProductId"))
                  orderby p.Field<int>("Rank") descending
                  select p)
                 .Take(250);
```